# How do I install Ubuntu on my HP Mini 1000 after HDD has been wiped?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, software-installation, uninstall

I bought an HP Mini about a year ago and I've never been able to use it. My friend sold it to me and it was a great little machine when I first looked at it. It was running Windows 7 but he decided to wipe the entire HDD (including the recovery partition). It doesn't have a optical drive.

Anyway, I have no idea what the computer needs at this point. I was able to make a boot drive for Ubuntu on a thumb drive and it works.. Barely. It's super slow and never stops reminding me I'm out of space. I want to install Ubuntu and be some with it but I'm not sure how... Or if the thing even has enough space for it.

I tried installing it, running it.. Nothing is working and I guess it's because it needs drivers but how do I know which ones I need? It seems like it should be so simple but every time I try something else I end up putting it back in the closet for another 3 months. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: There should be no issue installing Ubuntu 32-bit (!) from a pen drive. To get directions please [edit] your question to report **all** errors you get.

Comment: Mini 100 or 1000?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm not sure if I asked the right thing because when he wrote out his info he also wiped out the factory reset partition so I don't think the computer knows what to do when I try to install it... OK looking at all these q and a and it's all gibberish so I wasnt sure if I had given all the info you needed. I'm sure the biggest problem is my lack of computer knowledge.

Comment: You don't need any of the 'factory' or recovery content. You can install Ubuntu regardless. *You just need an install DVD or USB.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install Ubuntu **14.04.2 LTS** (32-bit), from USB. *I have done this successfully on 20 (or more) HP 210-1000s Netbooks (and similar/earlier models).* Check elsewhere on this forum on how to create the USB installer.

It needs to be **32-bit**, due to issues with **Intel Atom** graphics chipset/drivers.

You may have issues with WiFi, but check output from: **`dmesg | grep -e b43 -e Broadcom -e 43xx`**

Fix is: (using Ethernet cable)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

To confirm:

```
dmesg | grep -e b43 -e Broadcom -e 43xx
```

Comment: linux-firmware-nonfree is depreciated. You can't install it.

Comment: On **14.04** ? *I have not had that problem.*

Comment: Yes, on 14.04. firmware-b43-installer is used instead.

Comment: It will not install b43 firmware. It has been removed due to legal reasons. firmware-b43-installer downloads and installs firmware from broadcom. You can easily find this information instead of arguing.